# Go from there/go that way

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I was working and my brother started poking me because   he had to go out through the door. But I was busy and said :

> Go from there. (There are two doors in the room).

And if he asks me to move, can I still use:

> Go from there. (While pointing in that direction).

So is it used or will "go that way" be used? Is the use of "go from there" natural and is it used?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

*go from that door* is incorrect.

**You can correctly say**

*Go that way*

*Go the other way*

*Go through the other door*

*Use the other door*

*Go via that door*

---

**How to correctly use "go from"**

*If you want to go from London to Europe, you can fly from Gatwick airport or Heathrow airport.*

Answer (score 0):

From is used to show ***where somebody/something starts***

> Walk away from me.
>   Go from there.

From is used to specify that you are not expected to be in the place you are in.

So you cannot use ***go from there*** in that sense.

Comment: So it can't be used? So in the sentence you used above, is the use of "go from there" natural?